# Sub folder CSS Template Headers that are read by Admin panel

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sass

I'm in the process of creating a Wordpress theme that will have several different setup options based on input from the administrator.  One of the options will be to have a Zurb or Basic type layout.

I'm working with SCSS and want to have my stylesheets in a separate sub folder from the main theme files, cleanliness aside this is the easiest way for me to build/upload the files using my configuration of Sublime Text. I've been able to accomplish this easily enough and tell WP where to find the CSS folders for the specific setups.  But WP STILL requires me to have a style.css document in the root of the theme or the admin panel will tell me the theme is broken.  I realize this is due to WP looking for the Theme Header information located in the style.css/index.php files.  Is there a way to tell Wordpress to look else where for the Theme Header info?

I know you can `@import` the CSS files into this main style.css easily enough.  I however would prefer that the style.css file in the main folder not exist entirely.

Is there a function call / hook / filter / ect. that can be used to tell the WP admin panel that the main template/stylesheet files are actually in a different sub folder?  All of the other articles I've read on the subject will explain how to do the `@import` feature into the main style.css file, or suggest using `stylesheet_directory_uri();`. Both of these methods still require you to have a style.css in the root folder.  I haven't seen a suggestion that actually addresses forcing WP to handle it differently.

Even if this means editing the core (which is something I normally would never do) I'm fine with that.  I just want to know how. The solutions I mentioned above will solve my problem if all else fails.

Comment: hi voodooGQ, your question can also be answered better here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I tried there first and wasn't getting many hits. Figured I'd try the wider community here. (not sure if that's OK to repost questions across the network but didn't find anything against it)

Answer (score 0):

A theme **must** have a `style.css`... WP uses the top comment block to look for things like `Theme Name: xxx`, without it your theme is not *visible* to WP. *(You don't need to have any actual css in it, just the comment block.)*

As to the CSS... here's some `functions.php` code to get you started:

```
/**
 * This function is attached to the admin_menu action hook.
 */
function yourgreatthemeprefix_admin_menu() {
  wp_enqueue_style('someuniqueslug',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/yoursuperduperadminonly.css');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'yourgreatthemeprefix_admin_menu' );
```

Good luck...

Comment: As noted in the question `get_template_directory_uri()` is already a suggestion I am aware of.  A theme must have a style.css in its default form, however, there has to be somewhere in the core that states how/where Wordpress looks for that information.  It stands to reason that if it didn't have that coded somewhere than it wouldn't function as it does.

The question is, where is that code and how to modify it.  Thank you for your answer but it does not solve the question at hand.

Comment: Thank you! I'm certainly aware of the risks associated with this and do not recommend anyone doing it, but I'm glad I finally got an answer.  If you edit your answer to the information in your comment I'll check this off as correct/answered.  Thanks again!